# How to solve differential equations $ \frac{dy}{dx}=3x+2y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=3x+2y$$

---

I read that a differential equation of type 1 is solved as followed:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=g(x)$$
$$y=\int{dy}=\int{g(x)}dx$$

But it is not possible to isolate dy as we also have the "2y" expression.

How do I go about solving it?

Comment: Plz mark an answer as accepted by clicking $\checkmark$ below the answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can solve the DE using Integrating Factor Method.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} - 2y = 3x$$

The integrating factor:

$$e^{\int{-2 dx}} = e^{-2x}$$.

Multiplying both sides by $e^{-2x}$, we get:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(ye^{-2x}\right) = 3xe^{-2x}$$

Have left out some details for you to work them out.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: differentiate it to get
$$y''=3+2y'$$
$$\frac{y''}{2y'+3}=1$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\log(2y'+3)=x+C$$
$$2y'+3=Ke^{2x}$$
then you can integrate it depending on
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=g(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Write $\;y'-2y=3x\;$ , and put

$$\mu(x)=e^{\int(-2) \,dx}=e^{-2x}$$

and check now the general solution is

$$y=\frac{\int (\mu(x)\cdot2x)\,dx + C}{\mu(x)}\;,\;\;C=\text{ a constant}$$

Answer (score 2):

With substitution $u=3x+2y$ then 
$$\dfrac{du}{dx}=u'=3+2y'=3+2u$$
and
$$\dfrac{du}{3+2u}=dx$$
$$\ln(3+2u)=2x+C$$